# Index Management in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, indexing, indexer, magento-2.0

Can anyone tell me how does re indexing work in **Magento 2**.

Right now there are two options - Update on save and Update by schedule.

But like in **Magento 1** there is no option for manual re index.

It is not updating upon save. Cannot choose update by schedule option because i'm running my magento 2 in localhost which doesn't support cron.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you need to manually reindex you can refer to this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139088/2380

Answer (score 5):

In magento2 You can run index management using command line.To reindex check below steps

1. Log in to the Magento server as, or switch to, a user who has permissions to write to the Magento file system. One way to do this is to switch to the Magento file system owner.
2. To run Magento commands from any directory, add /bin to your system PATH.

After reaching magento2 root directory run below command

`magento indexer:reindex`

For windows environment run below command

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

You can read more about this at this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html) or this [link](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-index-management.html)

[Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html)

Comment: I'm running my magento 2 on localhost - xampp

Comment: on windows system ?@Swetha

Comment: your magentofolder directory for example   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2> php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: @pratik u mean i can run this in cmd prompt? isnt it a shell command?

Comment: yes its command ,,Which OS you are using ? @Swetha

Comment: Im using windows 7

Comment: Then open command promot and go to your magento2 directory from cmd and run php bin/magento indexer:reindex command ,,It will reindex your data @Swetha

Comment: Please do not forget this will only work if you have added the php.exe to your PATH in the Environment Variables. Please see http://willj.co/2012/10/run-wamp-php-windows-7-command-line/

Comment: Accept the answer if you find it helpful @Swetha

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it will work for indexing in Magento 2

**Get list of available indexing in Magento 2**

> magento indexer:info

**How to check status of indexer**
Following command will get you the status of all the indexer whether indexing is required or ready.

> magento indexer:status

You can also check status of individual indexer: let say i want to check status of catalog_category_product

> magento indexer:status catalog_category_product

**How to reindex all available indexing in Magento 2**

> magento indexer:reindex

In case you fill memory limit, try this command

> -dmemory_limit=2G magento indexer:reindex