# Magento ver. 2.1.0 - Index Management without SSH/Shell Access?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, index, ssh

Is it possible to **do Index Management without SSH/Shell Access** in Magento ver. 2.1.0 ?

Comment: In magento 1 you can just access the backend, go to System > Index and regenerate them. Doesn't this work for Mage 2?

Comment: if it did i wouldn't be asking. Even the backend looks totally different now.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt no you can reindex from M2 backend. Here's a small module I just wrote to do so: https://github.com/digitalpianism/reindex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Module link

After your question I ended up developping a small module for that. It is available here: https://github.com/digitalpianism/reindex

### Module Code

But here is the how to:

`app/code/DigitalPianism/Reindex/etc/module.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="DigitalPianism_Reindex" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Index"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`app/code/DigitalPianism/Reindex/etc/acl.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::system">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::tools">
                        <resource id="DigitalPianism_Reindex::reindex" title="Reindex" translate="title" sortOrder="30" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

`app/code/DigitalPianism/Reindex/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="reindex" frontName="reindex">
            <module name="DigitalPianism_Reindex" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now we add a new mass action to the index grid mass actions dropdown:

`app/code/DigitalPianism/Reindex/view/adminhtml/layout/indexer_indexer_list_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.indexer.grid.grid.massaction">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="reindex" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reindex</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">reindex/reindex/reindex</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Finally we create the controller that will handle the reindex:

`app/code/DigitalPianism/Reindex/Controller/Adminhtml/Reindex/Reindex.php`

```
<?php

namespace DigitalPianism\Reindex\Controller\Adminhtml\Reindex;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

/**
 * Class Index
 * @package DigitalPianism\Reindex\Controller\Adminhtml\Reindex
 */
class Reindex extends Action
{
    /**
     * Check the permission to run it
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('DigitalPianism_Reindex::reindex');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $indexerIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('indexer_ids');
        if (!is_array($indexerIds)) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please select indexers.'));
        } else {
            try {
                foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
                    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterface $model */
                    $model = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexerId);
                    $model->reindexAll();
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __('%1 indexer(s) were reindexed.', count($indexerIds))
                );
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException(
                    $e,
                    __("We couldn't reindex indexer(s)' because of an error.")
                );
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('indexer/indexer/list');
    }
}
```

`app/code/DigitalPianism/Reindex/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'DigitalPianism_Reindex',
    __DIR__
);
```

### How to

First enable the module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable DigitalPianism_Reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Then go to System > Index Management, select the indexes you want to reindex and choose reindex in the mass actions dropdown. Click the submit button and you're done

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create deploy.sh file in your project root directory and past following content

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /var/www/project/public_html/var/cache/ /var/www/project/public_html/var/page_cache/ /var/www/project/public_html/var/generation/ /var/www/project/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/ /var/www/project/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/ /var/www/project/public_html/pub/static/frontend/ /var/www/project/public_html/pub/static/_requirejs/
/var/www/project/public_html/bin/magento setup:upgrade
/var/www/project/public_html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
/var/www/project/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

now create deploy.php file in your project root directory and past following content

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$log = '';
$file = /*'/bin/bash ' .*/ dirname(__FILE__) . '/deploy.sh';
$cmds = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));
foreach($cmds as $k=>$cmd) {
if(substr($cmd, 0, 1) == '#') continue;
$log_bfr = '';
    $log_bfr = shell_exec("$cmd");
if(strlen($log_bfr) <= 0)    
 sleep(5);
   $log .= $cmd . '<br>' . $log_bfr;
}
ob_end_flush();
echo $log;
?>
```

whenever you need reindex ya cache clean you run this file.

Comment: I ran your code many times but its still not indexing anything :-(

Comment: you need to replace this path /var/www/project/public_html/var/cache/ and add your project application path.

Comment: I did that: /var/www/vhosts/my-site/my-site-sub-domain/var/

Comment: Do i need to increase server timeout ?